# Using \partcombine in lilypond SATB scores

Tags: lilypond

I have a choral piece which compiles without issue until I add the `PianoStaff`. I'm trying to use `\partcombine` to also produce a `PianoStaff` so that the piece is visible for piano.

I'm basing my changes on http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices#automatic-part-combining

```
\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff \with {midiInstrument = "flute"} <<
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice = "soprano" <<
          \global
          \sopranonotes
        >>
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "soprano" \sopranowords
      >>
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice = "alto" <<
          \global
          \altonotes
        >>
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "alto" \altowords
      >>
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice = "tenor" <<
          \global
          \tenornotes
        >>
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "tenor" \tenorwords
      >>
      \new Staff <<
        \new Voice = "bass" <<
          \global
          \bassnotes
        >>
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "bass" \basswords
      >>
    >>
    \new PianoStaff <<
      \new Staff <<
        \clef treble
        \partcombine \sopranonotes \altonotes
      >>
      \new Staff <<
        \clef bass
        \partcombine \tenornotes \altonotes
      >>
    >>
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

When I add the `PianoStaff` I get

```
choir.ly:366:9: error: unknown escaped string: `\partcombine'
        
        \partcombine \sopranonotes \altonotes
choir.ly:366:9: error: string outside of text script or \lyricmode
        
        \partcombine \sopranonotes \altonotes
```

Comment: Cheers. I've posted the whole `choir.ly` at https://github.com/timburgess/High_Country_Baxter  Once the cause is deduced, I can edit the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question there is a link to the v2.18 documentation, which uses `\partcombine`.

But your code is written in version 2.23.  And, according to the [2.23 documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices#automatic-part-combining) of the corresponding page:  The up to date syntax is `\partCombine` (with a capital C).